# Order of compiling and linking for multiple attribute directive in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I have two attribute directive called `myFoo` and `myBar`. These directives are defined with `restrict: 'A'`.

Then I have an element

```
<div my-foo my-bar></div>
```

In what order would the compiling/linking functions be called? Does `my-foo`'s compile always be called before `my-bar`'s compile ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to @valepu's answer here is the description for the `priority` property for the DDO (Directive Definition Object):

**TL;DR** The default `priority` is `0` and if you wish to change the order in which elements get compiled you'd have to increase the `priority` for the element(s).

> When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element,
>   sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives
>   are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives before their
>   compile functions get called. Priority is defined as a number.
>   Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first.
>   Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link
>   functions are run in reverse order. The order of directives with the
>   same priority is undefined. The default priority is 0.

In your case, if you do not specify the `priority` for your directives, `my-bar` will be compiled first followed by `my-foo`. However, notice that the controller gets initialized first, then the `pre` followed by the `post` link function. Also, the order is important here: Angular compiles the directives alternating. The follownig is my `console.log` printing which shows the process:

```
bar controller
foo controller
pre bar
pre foo
post foo
post bar
```

If you wish to play around, I have set up a [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/T4L0Q2ioLs6xf4xZqotp?p=preview).

Now, if you change the `priority` to `priority: 1` you will get the following output:

```
foo controller
bar controller
pre foo
pre bar 
post bar
post foo
```

As you can see, it starts with `myFoo` and goes on to `myBar`. So `myFoo` now has a higher priority.

**Update 1**

Question:

> How do you deal with a sititation, in which two different vendor directives (A and B) depend on each other and the order of execution is important? Is it possible without changing the vedor's settings?

I would suggest to implement a *decorator* as follows:

```
app.config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('myFooDirective', function($delegate) {
        var directive = $delegate[0];
        directive.priority = 9;
        return $delegate;
    });
});
```

Usually, a decorator intercepts the creation of a service, allowing it to override or modify the behaviour of a service. However, you could also decorate your directive as shown above. In the decorator you could set the priority to your needs to effect the order of execution. As far as I know the `priority` property is the only way to control the order in which the directives get applied. When using a decorator you modify / override the `priority` property but not directly its settings in case you don't mean the DDO.

The Plunker above is also updated with the decorator implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One question: Would my-bar's initializers always be called before my-foo's initializers? I want to know how would you deal with such situation... such as if ever encountered a case where two different vendors provide two different attribute directives (let's say A and B), and the vendors probably never knew of one another's existence. Since the order of invocation may affect the overall behavior of the tag, how can I guarantee that attribute A is invoked before attribute B without changing the vendor's setting?

Comment: Thank you for a clean solution. Yes, when I say not messing with vendor's setting, I mean not messing with the DDO that comes with the plugin/vendor

Comment: I think there is no other way but changing the priority.

Answer (score 3):

No,
Directives have a field called "priority" which tells angular when they have to be compiled. The bigger the priority the earlier they will be compiled. So, in your case, the directives will always be compiled in the same order (no matter how you write them in the tag) and this order depends on their priority field (default is 0).

from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

> **priority**
>
> When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element,
>   sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives
>   are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives before their
>   compile functions get called. Priority is defined as a number.
>   Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first.
>   Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link
>   functions are run in reverse order. The order of directives with the
>   same priority is undefined. The default priority is 0.

```
var myModule = angular.module(...);
myModule.directive('directiveName', function factory(injectables) {
  var directiveDefinitionObject = {
    priority: 0, //This is the priority field
    /* ....... */
  };
  return directiveDefinitionObject;
});
```

This article seems to explain quite well how priority works in different cases: http://www.newyyz.com/blog/2014/12/15/understanding-priorities-in-angularjs-directive-definition-objects/

Comment: " So, in your case, the directives will always be compiled in the same order"
If both directives have the same priority, do that mean that we cannot exactly determine which one of the directive (with the same priority) are compiled first? I.e, 50-50 chance that first attribute is compiled first.

Comment: In the article i linked at the end of the post it says that they are compiled in alphabetic order